Wrong result for symbolic input in PolygonAngle
One to be afraid to even mention the word bug.
So I will wait for an explanation why this is not a bug.
First case - substitution after applying PolygonAngle.
Second case - substitution before applying PolygonAngle.
Of course the latter provides correct outputs.
coo = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {p1, q1}, {p2, q2}, {p3, q3}, {p4, q4}};
subst = Thread[{p1, q1, p2, q2, p3, q3, p4, q4} -> {3/2, -(Sqrt[3]/2),
      1, -Sqrt[3], 0, -Sqrt[3], -(1/2), -(Sqrt[3]/2)}];

{PolygonAngle[Polygon@coo] /. subst, 
 PolygonAngle[Polygon@coo /. subst]}

{PolygonAngle[Polygon@coo, "Interior"] /. subst, 
 PolygonAngle[Polygon@coo /. subst, "Interior"]}

{PolygonAngle[Polygon@coo, "Exterior"] /. subst, 
 PolygonAngle[Polygon@coo /. subst, "Exterior"]}

{PolygonAngle[Polygon@coo, "FullExterior"] /. subst, 
 PolygonAngle[Polygon@coo /. subst, "FullExterior"]}´




I haven't done a thorough check, but I'm not convinced yet that we should expect them to be equal. Once we introduce an ArcCos we get some ambiguity, and I don't see you doing anything to force the correct choice. Maybe I'm not thinking about it correctly.

What choice? "Interior" specifies I want interior angle.

I think they should add to documentation "PolygonAngle gives generic values for symbolic parameters" if this is the case.

It's weird indeed. Comparing First@PolygonAngle[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {a, b}}]] and PolygonAngle[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {a, b}}], {0, 0}], they should give the same answer, right?

@Domen Of course they should, if you want to have a function that is consistent with every possible form of input.

Yeah, so it looks like the problem is only there if you do PolygonAngle without specifying the vertex. If you do Table[PolygonAngle[Polygon@coo, c], {c, coo}] /. subst, all is fine. Write to the WRI :)

Extended comment
Again, I may be thinking about this incorrectly, but maybe some purpose will be served by trying to explain my previous comment. Let's start with a simpler expression:
coords = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, p}, {-1, 1}}

Consider these two possible replacements:
Graphics[Polygon[coords /. p -> .9]]


Graphics[Polygon[coords /. p -> 1.1]]


Now, if we ask Mathematica to give us the polygon angles before the replacement, we get
PolygonAngle[Polygon[coords]]
(* {(3*Pi)/2, 
    2*Pi - ArcCos[(2 - p)/Sqrt[4 + 2*(-2 + p)*p]], 
    2*Pi - ArcCos[((-2 + p)*p)/(1 + (-1 + p)^2)], 
    2*Pi - ArcCos[(2 - p)/Sqrt[4 + 2*(-2 + p)*p]]} *)

At this point maybe we could object that Mathematica shouldn't have given us anything at all, or that it should have come up with an answer that wasn't ambiguous, but since we only have this to work with, my point is that from this point on, we've "lost" critical information about the original polygon. What I meant by ambiguity is this:
sol1 = PolygonAngle[Polygon[coords /. p -> .9]]
(* {0.68573, 1.5708, 0.68573, 3.34093} *)

Solve[2 \[Pi] - ArcCos[((-2 + p) p)/(1 + (-1 + p)^2)] == sol1[[4]], {p}]
(* {{p -> 0.9}, {p -> 1.1}} *)

So, it seems to me that if you try PolygonAngle with symbolic coordinates, Mathematica will try to give you a result, but the formula it uses depends on trig functions that can only be inverted with arbitrarily chosen constraints.
Now, I realize this doesn't directly address your specific complaint about the result. I think you'd be more disturbed by the 3 Pi /2. My point is just that by introducing symbolic values, maybe we're subverting the use of PolygonAngle and therefore can't really expect sensible outcomes. I don't think PolygonAngle is intended to be analogous to Solve. I think it's just very literally supposed to apply a trig-based formula to the inputs.

In documentation of PolygonAngle we can read "PolygonAngle can be used with symbolic polygons in GeometricScene." Suppose I put in GeometricScene condition that some interior angle should be less than Pi but if I use for this purpose PolygonAngle I get wrong results. I think the output of PolygonAngle is generic for symbolic parameters (i.e. like if interior and exterior angles were interchangeable). But it is not mentioned in documentation.

Well, we're not using GeometricScene. And one interpretation of that part of the documentation would conclude that PolygonAngle cannot be used for symbolic polygons outside of the context of GeometricScene. Do you have an example with GeometricScene that is not working as expected? I don't remember ever using GeometricScene, so I probably couldn't comment anyway. (FWIW, GeometricScene is labeled as experimental.)
